# Magic zoom plus slider was not displayed on home page in magento-1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I used magento 1.9 version. And I install the magiczoomplus slider and followed the given steps. But in a final step the complier status will not change to as 'enable'. So the slider was not displayed on home page. How can I display that slider on home page?

The steps are:

1.Go to System -> Cache Management and flush the cache

2.Change the settings as you wish via the Magic Toolbox -> Magic Zoom Plus™ settings menu

3.If you disabled Magento Compiler, enable it again

Answer (score 0):

The full instructions of how to install Magic Zoom Plus on Magento can be found here:

https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/modules/magento/

If you continue to experience an issue, please contact our Technical team who will be able to help you:

https://www.magictoolbox.com/contact/

Thanks!

Magic Toolbox